# How to modify a web page with a Firefox extension but with a side bar panel and not a context menu

Tags: javascript, html, browser, firefox-addon

I'd like to execute a JavaScript file on a specific webpage to control the dom of this last one. I tried the same kind of things of Mozilla documentation, on this page :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Modify_a_web_page

But, my case concern a lateral bar., and when I  add a `buttonInMySideBar.addEventListener("click",myFunc);` the line that should execute my js file in myFunc, is not executed when I click on my button. I don't understand what I should do. Here are my different files. If anyone could give me some tips, I would be grateful. I based my extension on annotatepage. My final purpose is to autofill a form on a specific web page.

Here's my manifest.json

```html
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Web page annotator",
  "description": "Displays a sidebar that lets you take notes on web pages.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "54.0a1"
    }
  },

  "sidebar_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/star.png",
    "default_title" : "Facturation ",
    "default_panel": "sidebar/panel.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs", 
    "contextMenus", 

  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "sidebar/panel.js"
    ]
  },


  "commands": {
    "_execute_sidebar_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Here is my panel.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="panel.css"/>
    <script src="jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="boutton" >Cliquez ICI </button>    
    <p class="content"> Le text s'affichera ici </p>
    
  </div>

  <script src="panel.js"></script>
  <script src="content-scritpt.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-csv/src/jquery.csv.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

And my problematic file background-script is this one : panel.js:

```html
bouttonAutoFillForm.addEventListener("click", autoFill); 

function autoFill(){
  $(".content").text("It's working only for the html here"); 
  // browser.tabs.executeScript - is not executing with this // extension, but well with an exemple firefox extension. 
  browser.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "content_script.js"
});
}
```

Here are some pictures of my sidebar

[image]

**In conclusion, how can I run the line `browser.tabs.executeScript` when I click on a button in the side panel? Should the listener be on the browser object? How can I manage this case?**

Comment: It's probably a permission problem. Does `browser.tabs.executeScript()` throw any errors? See https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/debugging/

Comment: Yes thanks it was a little mistake of that kind